# Emacs Keyboard Shortcuts in Atmel Studio

Tags: emacs, keyboard, atmelstudio

Has anyone found a way to have Emacs keyboard shortcuts in Atmel Studio 6? I realize it is built on Visual Studio and there is an Emacs Emulation extension for Visual Studio. I do not see the Emacs Emulation extension in the Extension manager in Atmel Studio. The Emacs Emulation extension is downloadable, I just can't figure out how to make Atmel Studio aware of it on my system or if there is a better way to set Emacs keybindings in Atmel Studio.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

To install Visual Studio vsix extensions into Atmel Studio, open the vsix in your favourite zip program, and edit the 'extension.vsixmanifest' file inside it. Under the  tag, add the following element (change version to fit your need).

```
<IsolatedShell Version="6.1">AtmelStudio</IsolatedShell>
```

See for instance the AStyle extension manifest for the structure: https://code.google.com/p/astyle-extension/source/browse/trunk/+astyle-extension/AStyleExtension/source.extension.vsixmanifest?r=23

Answer (score 0):

@xoriath's answer didn't work for me with Atmel Studio 7 (note that I changed the "6.1" to "7.0"). The installer simply says that it doesn't recognize the extension. Here's part of the log file:

```
11/2/2019 8:15:59 AM - Searching for applicable products...
11/2/2019 8:15:59 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
11/2/2019 8:15:59 AM - Found installed product - AtmelStudio
11/2/2019 8:15:59 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

Where is this "IsolatedShell" section supposed to be inserted- which tag?

I tried putting it in every section of the XML file, all to no avail. I also tried adding a  tag, and inserting it there, as per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/vs-shell-deployment?view=vs-2019 . But that didn't work either.

Update: I did change the Installation tag to look like this:

```
  <Installation InstalledByMsi="false" AllUsers="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="AtmelStudio" Version="[7.0]" />
  </Installation>
```

And it appeared to work, but all the Emacs key entries have no mapping. So I doubt if this extension works anymore.